# Split a database of mol2 molecules into N smaller sets

Tags: python, bash

I got a big set of molecules from the zinc database (http://zinc.docking.org/), in mol2 (http://tripos.com/index.php?family=modules,SimplePage,,,&page=sup_mol2&s=0) format. I would like to be able to split this database into an arbitrary set of N smaller databases. What is the best scripting approach in either python, bash or perl for this? I read about openbabel, but it can only generate sets of individual molecules.

If not, I can also convert mol2 to another more convenient format

Thaks

Comment: what is the criterion to perform the split ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csplit` can separate the file into individual molecules:

```
csplit ~/Download/zinc.mol2 '/@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE/' '{*}'
```

If you want something more clever then you can read each molecule into a list or array as a string and then spit out as many as you like into each file.

Comment: thanks

what is the point of '{*}'? I get an error

Each mol2 molecule starts with the TRIPOS header as you said but ends with 2 blank lines

Comment: The {*} tells csplit to repeat the previous pattern until the end of the file. Without it csplit will only create 2 files, one containing everything up to the first match, and the other containing everything from the first match to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this in linux:

```
gawk -v RS="@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE" 'NF{ print RS$0 > "zinc"++n".mol2" }' zinc.mol2
```